# Stop re-sharing of bi report from user end

Tags: powerbi

I am a new user of power bi. I am currently using free account of power bi and used share to web feature to share my report publicly.

Using free account i want to share my report with multiple users while stopping my report consumers to re-share the report.  If that is not possible using free account then is it possible to buy only one pro account and attain my objective defined above?

Buying multiple pro accounts for each individual is not possible as there would be many consumers of my report. Buying premium account is also not possible as it is too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to share reports is from Pro User to Pro User, via Workspaces or direct sharing or App. In the sharing options for the report to the other users you can turn off the allow the recipients to share as well. Or you can allow workspace consumers to be read only.

[image]

Sharing using the 'Share to Web' function creates a publicly accessible URL, if anyone passes that URL to anyone else, they will be able to see it, and it is NOT secure, and you can't limit/restrict access.

Answer (score 0):

For these use cases, the best solution is to embed the report in an (web) application. Start with [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers).